# Is the logic used inside servlets, itself the model, or the data they handle and pass to the jsp is the model?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, servlets

In the **MVC** architecture, the controller is what decides which user request is to handled by which component (which servlet, in the case of **Java EE**). Then, is the logic used inside the servlet (calling business methods or EJBs, etc) which is used to create the data that should be given to the view, called the model ?

In some books, its written that the servlet passes the model to the JSPs. In this sense, model is the data that is passed to the JSP. What's the correct meaning of 'model' in a typical **Java EE architecture** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model can concern both the "business model" and the "data model". The business model is also known as "business delegates", "domain objects", "service facades" or anything in this sense. In a well designed Java EE web application according the standards, it are the EJB classes which does **not** use JPA or any DB access logic *directly* but delegate further to other EJB classes which are pure DAO objects.

E.g.

```
@Stateless
public class ShoppingServiceLocal implements ShoppingService {

    @EJB
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @EJB
    private OrderDAO orderDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Product> searchProducts(String query) {
        return productDAO.find(query);
    }

    @Override
    public Order orderProduct(User user, Product product, int quantity) {
        product.setAvailable(product.getAvailable() - quantity);
        productDAO.update(product);
        Order order = new Order(user.getId(), product.getId(), quantity);
        orderDAO.create(order);
        return order;
    }

}
```

Note that, since this is an EJB, the `ProductDAO#update()` and `OrderDAO#create()` are done in a single transaction. So if creating the order throws an exception, the edited availability won't be persisted as well.

The "data model" are the `Product`, `User` and `Order` in the above example, which are supposed to be JPA `@Entity` javabeans. This is all what the servlet (the controller) and JSP (the view) knows about.

Answer (score 2):

The model is the way you structured the data beneath your server. So, the model is not the data passed to the JSP, but the data structure you passed to the jsp.

When explaining the MVC pattern this doubts always come out. Some people say that the DTO (data transfer object) is the model, the jsp is the view and the actions executed on server are the controllers, but I have heard at least a different explanation in the case of Java EE architecture, which i can't remember right now.

However, i like your (and completed by me) point of view better than other things that i've heard so far.